# Exchange server actively refuses my connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchange-server

I'm writing a ASP.NET application used within our company. Now I want to send emails to some users via a email account on our exchange server.

I tried to use System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient, where a proprietary account and password are given to specify the credentials. But the code failed with following exception:
"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Is that due to Exchange Server policies to prevent spam? How can I get it to work?

Comment: Can you ask your sysadmin about this?  It could be a firewall issue.

Comment: When this happened to me it was something of a firewall issue.  Actually the exchange server was set to only accept mails from certain machines and my dev box had to be added to the whitelist.  Its a pretty common anti spam tactic.

Comment: Thank you all! I really appreciate it! Our loal IT crew told me I may have goto global IT and let them add me to the white list. But I'm curious, how exchange server tell outlook and my .net application? Thanks!

Comment: When Outlook is configured to connect to an Exchange server, it does not use SMTP to send mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message is normally received when there is nothing listening at the specified IP-address and port for a TCP connection. AFAIK the SMTP protocol uses TCP. Please make sure your server address is correct and that the server does not use a non-standard port.

Comment: What in case of local host? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I've previously experienced this when McAfee was blocking activity on port 25.  Took me ages to work it out as I just didn't think of it (I did verify my Windows firewall was allowing the connection).

Just a thought - might not be applicable in your situation.